# Custom array multidim values

Tags: php

I had a problem with my code. for example, I have an array like this :

```
[
    'a' => ['f', 'g'],
    'b' => ['h', 'i'],
    'c' => ['j', 'k']
]
```

I want to change my array to be like this:

```
[
    ['a' => 'f', 'b' => 'h', 'c' => 'j'],
    ['a' => 'g', 'b' => 'i', 'c' => 'k']
]
```

I need help to solve this. Thanks

Comment: For what strange cause you need to do that??

Comment: I want to make it json using arrays. if I use the example array above to convert to json, it would be difficult to call data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this on my local computer

```
<?php

$array = [
    'a' => ['f', 'g'],
    'b' => ['h', 'i'],
    'c' => ['j', 'k']
];

$ultimate_array = array();

foreach($array as $key1 => $child_array)
{
    foreach($child_array as $i => $key2)
    {
        if(empty($ultimate_array[$i])) $ultimate_array[$i] = array();
        $ultimate_array[$i][$key1] = $key2;
    }
}

print_r($ultimate_array);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple demonstration:

```
<?php    
$input = [
    'a' => ['f', 'g'],
    'b' => ['h', 'i'],
    'c' => ['j', 'k']
];
$output = [];

foreach ($input as $key=>$entries) {
    foreach ($entries as $entry) {
        $output[$key][] = $entry;
    }
}

var_dump($output);
```

---

Some would consider this variant more elegant:

```
<?php

$input = [
    'a' => ['f', 'g'],
    'b' => ['h', 'i'],
    'c' => ['j', 'k']
];
$output = [];

array_walk($input, function($entries, $key) use (&$output) {
    array_walk($entries, function($entry) use (&$output, $key) {
        $output[$key][] = $entry;
    });
});

var_dump($output);
```

---

The obvious output of both variants is:

```
array(3) {
  ["a"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "f"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "g"
  }
  ["b"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "h"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "i"
  }
  ["c"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "j"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "k"
  }
}
```